# Table with condition

Tags: list-manipulation

I have 2 lists of numbers `A = Range[16, 65]` and `B = Range[10, 16]`. I want to form all possible combinations $(a,b)$ of the elements in those lists such that $a - b > 5$. I can get what I want with:

```
Tuples[{A, B}] /. {a_, b_} /; a - b <= 5 -> Nothing
```

How can I get the same list using `Table`?

Comment: `Table[]` with `If[]` and `Nothing` ought to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Table[{a, b}, {a, 16, 65}, {b, 10, Min[16, a - 5 - 1]}] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

Comment: rather `Table[{a, b}, {a, 16, 65}, {b, 10, Min[16, a - 5]}] // Flatten[#, 1]&`...

Comment: @amrods Thanks! But I think it should be `Min[16, a - 5 - 1]` because `a - b > 5` means `b <= a - 6`

Answer (score 9):

To do it with `Table` modify your `Tuples` example:

```
Flatten[Table[If[a - b > 5, {a, b}, Nothing],
   {a, Range[16, 65]}, {b, Range[10, 16]}], 1];
```

If you are not committed to `Table` another idea is to use `Outer`

```
Flatten[Outer[If[#1 - #2 > 5, List[#1, #2], Nothing] &, 
   Range[16, 65], Range[10, 16]], 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pick`

```
Block[{t=Tuples[{A,B}]},Pick[t,-UnitStep[Apply[Subtract,t,{2}]+5],1]]
```

Comment: This does not appear to use `Table`, as requested in the question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey oh, yes......